# Data Grid view not reading null rows from image Column

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server

I am trying to read data from Data grid View in Windows Csharp Form and I need to populate the Picture box as soon as i select any other row from grid view.. Below is my code.. tried looking at various other forums yet i am getting the below error.

**"Unable to cast object of type 'System.DBNull' to type 'System.Byte[]'."**

```
enter code here if (!Convert.IsDBNull(row.Cells["empimg"]))
            {
                var data = (Byte[])(row.Cells["empimg"].Value);
                var stream = new MemoryStream(data);
                pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromStream(stream);
            }
            else
            {
                pictureBox1.Image = null;

            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are testing `IsDBNull` against the `Cell` instead of the `.Value`. Change your code to this:

```
if (row.Cells["emping"] != null && !Convert.IsDBNull(row.Cells["empimg"].Value))
{
    var data = (Byte[])(row.Cells["empimg"].Value);
    var stream = new MemoryStream(data);
    pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromStream(stream);
}
else
{
    pictureBox1.Image = null;
}
```